# Why does WinUICommunity.TitleBar not reflect to the current Light theme?

Tags: winui-3

1. The Prism framework provides the main window in this method:

   ```
        protected override void Initialize(IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
          base.Initialize(builder);

          Window = builder.Window;

          Window.Hide();

          Window.AppWindow.TitleBar.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;

          ThemeService = new ThemeService();
          ThemeService.PaintTitleBarButtons();
          ThemeService.Initialize(Window);

          MaxWindow();
        }
   ```

The method `PaintTitleBarButtons` seems having no effect.

```
    internal static void PaintTitleBarButtons(this IThemeService themeService)
    {
        themeService.ConfigTitleBar(new TitleBarCustomization
        {
            LightTitleBarButtons = new TitleBarButtons
            {
                ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Azure,
                ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.DarkGreen,
                BackgroundColor = Colors.Brown,
                ForegroundColor = Colors.Honeydew
            },
            DarkTitleBarButtons = new TitleBarButtons
            {
                ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Tan,
                ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.Teal,
                BackgroundColor = Colors.Violet,
                ForegroundColor = Colors.CadetBlue
            }
        });
    }
```

2. Then Prism creates the shell view in the following method:

   ```
   protected override UIElement CreateShell()
   {
     var shell = Container.Resolve<Shell>();
   #if WINDOWS
        shell.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            MainXamlRoot = (s as UIElement).XamlRoot;
        };
   #endif
        return shell;
    }
   ```
3. The shell view is being loaded as :

   ```
   <ContentControl
     x:Class="Weather.History.Mvvm.Views.Shell"
     xmlns:prismmvvm="using:Prism.Mvvm"
     xmlns:prism="using:Prism.Navigation.Regions"
     prismmvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
     xmlns:inf="using:Weather.History.Prism"
     xmlns:wuc="using:WinUICommunity"
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
     VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     Loaded="OnLoaded">
   <Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <wuc:TitleBar x:Name="TitleBar" Grid.Row="0">
        <wuc:TitleBar.Content>
            <RelativePanel>
                <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="SuggestBox"
                        PlaceholderText="City or village"
                        Width="250"
                        Height="30"
                        QueryIcon="Find"
                        TextChanged="ViewModel.OnType"
                        SuggestionChosen="ViewModel.OnSelect"
                        RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>

                <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar"
                     Width="250"
                     Height="1"
                     IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsProgressOn, Mode=OneWay}"
                     RelativePanel.Below="SuggestBox"
                     RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>

            </RelativePanel>
        </wuc:TitleBar.Content>
    </wuc:TitleBar>

    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Bind inf:RegionNames.CarouselView}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Bind inf:RegionNames.Console}" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
   </Grid>
   </ContentControl>
   ```
4. And finally the `OnLoaded` event is executed:

   ```
   private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      App.Window.SetTitleBar(TitleBar);
      App.EnableClicksOnTitlebar(SuggestBox);
   }
   ```
5. Light theme selected and the title bar remains dark, what am I doing wrong ?

[image]

When: `<Grid x:Name="TitleBar"/>` , so empty Grid employed =>

[image: When: , so empty Grid employed.]

There is also a `PipsPager` above an `AppBar` , which remains dark even while light theme is on:

[image]

Dark theme presents the same area like this (different background color but the same as title bar has) :

[image]

What's more, there is also a `WebView`, which never applies the dark theme: ( I dont know what to share about it because it is initialized in the view model and as for Xaml =>
`<ContentPresenter Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyWebView}" Grid.Column="1"/>` )

Furthermore there is a `ContentDialog`, which never applies the light theme.

Furthermore either `LiveCharts` has a [bug](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2/issues/1458) or WinUI is unable to display well the requested theme.

[image]

Comment: you should move `ConfigTitleBar` codes before `_themeService.Initialize` , all Config... codes should be written before Initialize method

Comment: I moved the init into the `OnLoaded` handler as last invocation as `App.ThemeService.Initialize(App.Window);` after `EnableClicksOnTitlebar` but to no avail.

Comment: @Katana, just tried with an empty Grid as title bar set, now the buttons remain dark.